# Good sources of example sentences?

Tags: sentence, resources

I have the impression that Deepl.com usually does a good job translating, such as in this sentence:

渋谷【しぶや】は偏愛【へんあい】が集【あつ】まる街【まち】、偏愛【へんあい】に寛容【かんよう】な街【まち】

*Shibuya is a town where eccentrics gather, and a town that is tolerant of eccentricity.*

https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASPD45RT6PCVUTIL023.html?iref=comtop_Culture_04

However, when I look up the word, I find...

偏愛【へんあい】favoritism; partiality

...which doesn't really make as much sense as Deepl's translation.
Even goo's entry doesn't include "eccentricity," and "partiality" doesn't make much sense in this context:

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/偏愛/#je-68580](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%81%8F%E6%84%9B/#je-68580)

I could not find many example sentences for this word in wwwjdic, jisho, or weblio.

Are there other good sources of example sentences that would allow me to check a machine translation against a word's use in other contexts?

Comment: Resource requests belong on the meta site: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

偏愛 refers to a (usually eccentric and/or obsessive) attitude of loving only one thing/person, as described in [this entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%81%8F%E6%84%9B/#jn-200124). In the context of that article, 偏愛 refers to maniac enthusiasm or obsessive love toward something, not eccentric people nor the concept of eccentricity itself. Even though DeepL's translation seems to make sense somehow, I'd say it's not a good translation.

When you want many real example sentences, check a corpus like [BCCWJ](https://ccd.ninjal.ac.jp/bccwj/) or [NLT](https://tsukubawebcorpus.jp/).